# How stosd works in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, analysis, malware

Sorry for this question .. just wanted to understand how stosd works in assembly when EAX is zero

```
mov ecx, 41
lea edi, [variable]
xor eax, eax
rep stosd
```

I was debugging a malware with these instructions and with each stosd i can see windows directories paths are coming when following edi in dump.

But from where these directories are comming when EAX is zero and not referring to any variable?

Comment: `rep stosd` is `wmemset(edi, eax, ecx)` - it just stores zeros in your case.  But it also increments EDI, leaving it pointing to the end of the buffer.

Comment: Thanks ... @Peter .. now i got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the pointers *already* stored in the array pointed by `edi`, *before* each `stosd` overwrites them with zero.

[`stosd` writes `eax` to `edi` and increments it by four](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/stos:stosb:stosw:stosd:stosq) (assuming the `DF` flag is not set, which is usually the case).

That snippet is equivalent to `memset(variable, 0, 41*4)`.